# Run .exe with daemon or better solutions to get something similar to windows service (mac and linux)?

Tags: linux, macos, mono, daemon

I was wondering if i can run a exe with daemons in mac and linux or do you have any other solutions to do something similar to a windows service that is a scheduler ? I know i can use crontab but i was wondering if there was other way to do it.

Thx

Comment: David, you are meaning to say that you want to invoke a command at a given time instance ?

Comment: well i want to evoke an action with a scheduler

Answer (score 3):

On OS X, the preferred way of doing things like this is with launchd daemons.  You create a .plist file with information about what program to run, parameters to pass it, and what conditions to start it under (i.e. at certain times, when a network connection is received on a certain port, or just run always), and various other options.  [Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) provides a handy GUI for creating the .plist, or just read the [Apple LAUNCHD docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) and create it yourself.  Put the .plist in /Library/LaunchDaemons, and either reboot or activate it with `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/whatever.plist`.

A warning about using launchd: most daemon-type programs for unix will "daemonize" themselves -- they drop into the background, and generally detach themselves from the program that started them.  Launchd doesn't like this.  It wants to keep watch over its children, so that it can monitor their status, relaunch them if necessary, etc.  So you may either need to tell the program not to daemonize, or add an option to the .plist to tell launchd not to freak out if the program appears to quit.

Answer (score 1):

Linux alternative to windows NT services are daemons. You can read a little more about it
[here](http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html).

You also start executables by scripts located in "/etc/init.d" Just look at one of those scripts for reference. If you want to make a task or executable start at a given time use a crontab. It is made for this purpose and I don't see why use something else.

If you have a mono executable probably the easiest way is just to make a script in "init.d" if you want to start when system starts or make a crontab entry. It is realy easy. Here you can find a [simple reference](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm).